# Пропал звук Xubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xubuntu

После повышения громкости до 150% в pavucontrol пропал звук, думал сгорела карта, но через некоторое время звук снова появился на пару минут, и также внезапно исчез. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: `pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start` пробовал?

Comment: @donRumata, не помогает пробовал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала  провести диагностику - загрузиться с LiveCD.
Нет звука - вероятность большая технической поломки, решение: использовать внешнюю аудио-карту.

Comment: Крч проблемы где-то в железе, переустановил систему загружался с флешки все равно не работает. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй реинициализировать командой:  **alsactl init**